# friendly_id thowing error while creating a new user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

I have a model User which is polymorphically associated with Person and Company model.

I am using friendly_id to show permalinks for both Person and Company.

Person has first_name attribute and I put the following in my model.

```
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :first_name
```

Now when I update my existing entries then the slug gets created perfectly. But issue arises when I try creating a new use which throws a routing error.

Secondly, every person has one user and user has a username, so when I try this following command, then the update and new record both throws unknown method username for nil class error.

```
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :person_permalink, use: [:slugged, :history]

def person_permalink
  "#{self.user.username} #{self.name}"
end
```

Comment: _But issue arises when I try creating a new use which throws a routing error_ please provide more information on this. You're saying there's an error but not providing any stack traces

Answer (score 2):

I believe this may have to do with the `before_save` on the friendly_id.

more than likely the associated records and ids are not in sync at the time the friendly_id is being created and `self.user` is nil.

There is a similar issue with people attempting to use the primary key, ID table-column-value within the friendly_id.